# Snap mean coordinate to layer in QGIS and creating MCs for multiple shapefiles

Tags: qgis, vector, point

1: I wish to create a mean coordinate for a group of points. However, I would like the new point to be snapped to the nearest point from the set of points used to generate it.

How might one go about this, if at all possible?

2: I have come to the stage where I have many shapefiles I wish to create mean coordinates for. Is it possible to make QGIS generate these all in one go? As opposed to manually generating the coordinate through inputting one shapefile at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach would be to do it in a couple of steps.  First calculate the mean coordinate and then use that to select the nearest point from the original layer and save that as your new "mean".

**EDIT (more detail):**
Use `Vector->Analysis Tools->Mean Coordinates` to calculate your actual mean point.  Then you may be able to merely pick the point manually if it is obvious. Alternatively go use `Vector->Analysis Tools->Distance Matrix` tool to identify the nearest point(s).  The output of the distance matrix tool is a table.  I'd go this way if you have a lot of clusters each with their own mean.  You can then do a table join back to your points and select the points with the smallest value in the distance field from the join table for each cluster.  Whether you do the selection manually or by the distance matrix method, you then just save your selection as a new dataset.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate on the process please. I am very new to QGIS and haven't had much time practising the functions!

Comment: NP.  See my edits.

Comment: Great stuff, I've gone the manual route since the process requires some degree of subjectivity anyway. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Any idea why when i join the attribute table to the layer some of the values in the column are being entered as NULL? cheers

Comment: The usual reason is that there is no matching value in the join table

Comment: The problem is - where nodes are already sitting ontop of the other nodes, the distance matrix is returning NULL values. Is it possible to return a true value despite the two geometries being the same? It is working fine for 90% of the nodes, just the 10% where mean coordinates have been generated from 1 node only are causing a problem. I have a solution in excel, but I'd rather keep the labour process down and find a solution within QGIS, i'm sure it's something simple.